# How do you keep a UIButton on top (like a z-index) of a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a  `UITabBarController` with  `UITabBarItems` . I add a button on top of that which works fine until you use  `bottomBarHide` method. Then the button appears underneath the tab bar.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you screenshot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bringSubviewToFront should work:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```